# how do I get the currently selected cell of a notebook document with vscode API?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to get the currently selected cell of a notebook document in vscode. (a jupyter notebook) When inserting text to it's selection, it points to a random cell incorrectly.

The whole point is to insert some code into the currently selected cell.

Answer (score 0):

vscode v1.68 is adding a new notebook api, see [V1.68 Release Notes, notebook editor api](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_68.md#notebook-editor-api).  See if it returns the currently selected cell correctly.

It is a *preview feature* for now so you will have to test in the Insiders Build.

The example there is similar to your use case:

> The new `notebookWorkspaceEdit` API proposal allows extensions to edit
> the contents of a notebook. It replaces the previous
> `notebookEditorEdit` proposal.
>
> With the proposal, you can create workspace edits that insert,
> replace, or modify cells in a notebook:

```
const currentNotebook = vscode.window.activeNotebookEditor?.notebook;
if (currentNotebook) {
  const edit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
  edit.set(currentNotebook.uri, vscode.NotebookEdit.insertCells(/* index*/ 1, [
    // ... new notebook cell data
  ]));
  await vscode.workspace.applyEdit(edit);
}
```

Also see the other example there:

> The new `notebookWorkspaceEdit` API proposal allows extensions to edit
> the contents of a notebook. It replaces the previous
> `notebookEditorEdit` proposal.
>
> With the proposal, you can create workspace edits that insert,
> replace, or modify cells in a notebook:

```
const currentNotebook = vscode.window.activeNotebookEditor?.notebook;
if (currentNotebook) {
  const edit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
  edit.set(currentNotebook.uri, vscode.NotebookEdit.insertCells(/* index*/ 1, [
    // ... new notebook cell data
  ]));
  await vscode.workspace.applyEdit(edit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const activeNotebook = vscode.window.activeNotebookEditor;
  console.log(activeNotebook.selection);
```

Suppose the currently selected cell is the first one, the following code will print a notebookRange(0,1).

If you want to have all of the selected cells, you can use :

```
activeNotebook.selections; // notice the s !
```